# Web page loading time using java

Tags: java

How to know the time taken to load a web page using java..?Can any one help me regarding this..Thanks in advance..

Comment: question not clear. do you want to measure response time of your own JSP? or hit soem random URL and measure the response time in a java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebug which will give you the exact time, from the users' perspective.

If you want the server-side generation times, you can use a `Filter`. In its `doFilter(..)` method have something like:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
chain.doFilter(request, responsE);
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

Comment: At client side I'll suggest google-chrome too, which has an excellent embedded profiler tool

Comment: How I can achieve this at client side? I do not want to use any UI tools.